# select rows containing max value basing on another duplicated rows of a group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

I want to select rows by the maximum values of another column which would be the duplicated rows containing duplicated maximum values of a group.

This should contain three steps:
(1) group dataframe by column A;
(2) get duplicated rows with duplicated maximum values of column B;
(3) get rows if it contains maximum values of column C (if it is still duplicated, pick the first).

Example:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,3,4,2,4,3,3,2],
                        'B':[3,3,2,4,5,2,5,3,4,3],
                    'C':[80,85,88,90,70,83,85,90,90,70]})
```

[image]

```
df_result=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],
                        'B':[3,3,4,5],
                    'C':[85,70,90,85]})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a programming than a data science question, and would therefore be better suited for stackoverflow, but this can be achieved relatively easily using a combination of sorting and grouping:

```
(
    df
    # sort such that the first row is within each group is the one you want
    .sort_values(["A", "B", "C"], ascending=[True, False, False])
    # group based on column A
    .groupby("A")
    # select the first row within each group
    .first()
    # reset the index such that A is a column instead of the index
    .reset_index()
)
```

Which gives the following result:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 85 |
| 2 | 3 | 70 |
| 3 | 4 | 90 |
| 4 | 5 | 85 |